# Bootstrap CSS - aligning absolute positioned buttons and inputs

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/122/

I need to achieve the following:

- contain the inputs within the the parent ordered-list/definition-list
- have right edge of the arrow buttons sit flush against the right edge of each text input (thereby partly covering the inputs. I will later hide these and use jQuery to display on hover)

  ```
  HTML

  <div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span4">
    <form id="" class="well sidebar-nav">
      <dl>
          <dt><input type="text" class="counter nospace" name="myList_name" id="myList_name"/></dt>
          <dd>
              <ol>
                  <li><input type="text" name="myList_item_1" class="counter box" id="myList_item_1" /><div id="myList_chart_1" class="chart"><a class="btn" href="#">&uarr;</a><a class="btn" href="#">&darr;</a></div></li>
                  <li><input type="text" name="myList_item_2" class="counter box" id="myList_item_2" /><div id="myList_chart_2" class="chart"><a class="btn" href="#" style="z-index:0">&uarr;</a><a class="btn" href="#">&darr;</a></div></li>
                  <li><input type="text" name="myList_item_3" class="counter box" id="myList_item_3" /><div id="myList_chart_3" class="chart"><a class="btn" href="#">&uarr;</a><a class="btn" href="#">&darr;</a></div></li>
                  <li><input type="text" name="myList_item_4" class="counter box" id="myList_item_4" /><div id="myList_chart_4" class="chart"><a class="btn" href="#">&uarr;</a><a class="btn" href="#">&darr;</a></div></li>
                  <li><input type="text" name="myList_item_5" class="counter box" id="myList_item_5" /><div id="myList_chart_5" class="chart"><a class="btn" href="#">&uarr;</a><a class="btn" href="#">&darr;</a></div></li>
                  </ol>
          </dd>
      </dl>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>


  CSS

  @import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

  .sidebar-nav {
  padding: 9px 0;
  }
  .nav {
    list-style: decimal;
  }
  .counter {
    width: 100%;
  }
  dt {
    margin-left: 34px;
  }
  form dl dd ol {
    position: relative;
  }
  .box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }

  #myList_item_1, #myList_chart_1 { top: 0; }
  #myList_item_2, #myList_chart_2 { top: 36px; }
  #myList_item_3, #myList_chart_3 { top: 72px; }
  #myList_item_4, #myList_chart_4 { top: 108px; }
  #myList_item_5, #myList_chart_5 { top: 144px; }

  ol li {
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  .chart {
    width: 58px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Okay - I'm almost there:

http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/151/

It was pretty much as simple as applying right: 0; to the .chart class.

The only thing I'm still struggling with is aligning the buttons against the inputs.